# How to fix jw-modal selector issue in angular 8

Tags: angular, modal-dialog

I have the below code, when I run the command "npm run lint" in node.js I got error on the selector line 4 (The selector should be prefix by "app"). I tried do this: "app-jw-modal", all the modal content was appeared on the main page.

Is there and way to fix the prefix issue, as in the selector issue?

**comp.ts**

```
1. import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
2. import { ModalService } from './modal.service';

3. @Component({ 
4.  selector: 'jw-modal', 
    templateUrl: 'modal.component.html', 
    styleUrls: ['modal.component.less'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of fixing this issue.

**1.**

Change all instances of `jw-modal` to `app-jw-modal`. That will include anywhere the selector is currently being used.

If its refernced in any component like so:

```html
<jw-modal></jw-modal>
```

That becomes:

```html
<app-jw-modal></app-jw-modal>
```

**2.**

Modify the TSLint rule to satisfy your needs.

```
{
  "extends": "../../tslint.json",
  "rules": {
    "component-selector": [true, "element", "app", "kebab-case"]
  }
}
```

You can modify this rule, to choose what prefix is required, or you can turn off the rule.